# How to execute ARM binary instructions?

Tags: arm, qemu, instructions

let's say I have a file full of ARM processor instructions which are already represented as bytes. What is the best way to execute them directly with qemu-arm?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps asm `.incbin` (if that's the right GAS directive) into an object file you can link into an executable. (With the `_start` entry point on that code.)

Comment: arm instructions are only a tiny fraction of the problem its like saying I have a book written using the alphabet, how do I read a book.  The instruction set just gets you to the memory space and peripherals so executing instructinos can/will simply crash if you dont match it up with the system it was built/designed for.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is a bootable image, qemu can be started directly with the image file:

```sh
qemu-system-arm -hda data.img
```

where `data.img` is the name of your binary file.

Otherwise, as Peter Cordes wrote, the easiest way would be to create an ELF executable (see [How to run a bare metal ELF file on QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913745/how-to-run-a-bare-metal-elf-file-on-qemu?noredirect=1&lq=1)) and start it via

```sh
qemu-system-arm -kernel data.elf
```

where `data.elf` is the name of the created ELF executable.

*(too long for a comment, so I posted it as an answer)*

Comment: Your command lines won't work, because you haven't told QEMU which machine type to use...

Comment: Thats true, `-machine` need to be added.